# php web scraping using XPATH and JSON

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, jsonpath

I've been learning some web scraping using XPath in PHP and I have successfully scraped contents from many websites and using many selectors until I tried it with a JSON.

What I find quite weird is that when I run the command  `$x("//body/text()");` in the browser I get the desired result but there is something wrong in my code and I'm not aware what is it.

this is an example in viper-7 in which I successfully scrape odds from a website. [scraped Odds](http://viper-7.com/zqrA92)

On the other hand, I'm trying to use the same code to scrape a json right from the body and I can't seem to get it right. Not only did I try to use json_decode but also json_encode.

This is the code I can't seem to fix. [scrape JSON](http://viper-7.com/NrHoRE)

Comment: those who can do, those who can't scrape other peoples sites.

Comment: are you trying to scrape JSON from the body element?

Comment: Yes. But using Xpath because I could easily use something like  `$str = file_get_contents('https://www.realproperty.cl/mobilData.php?functName=getInmuebles&inmuebleID=561');
  $jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);`  yet XPath gives me more freedom later on using some classes I've created that work with it

Comment: Dagon, scraping is not supposed to be a bad thing. For me, is a matter of learning. I'm sorry if I conveyed the wrong message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search JSON, you should use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), not XPath:

```
<?php
    require_once('json.php');
    require_once('jsonpath.php');

    $parser = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);

    $json = file_get_contents('https://www.realproperty.cl/mobilData.php?functName=getInmuebles&inmuebleID=561');
    $o = $parser->decode($json);
    $result = jsonPath($o, "$..descripcion");

    echo '<ul>'."\n";
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        echo '    <li>'.$parser->encode($item).'</li>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>'."\n";
?>
```

You will need [jsonpath.php](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/PHP) and [json.php](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198)

This prints:

```
<ul>
    <li>"Edificio Trancura se encuentra ubicado en un importante sector residencial de la comuna de Las Condes, a pasos de Av. Crist\u00f3bal Col\u00f3n, cercano a diversos servicios como supermercados, restaurantes, farmacias, strip center, etc.\r\n\r\nEste proyecto cuenta con un innovador dise\u00f1o que incluye espacios de doble altura en los departamentos (3 dormitorios), lo que genera una gran sensaci\u00f3n de amplitud y a su vez permite un mejor ingreso de luz natural.\r\n\r\nRecibimos su propiedad en parte de pago."</li>
    <li>"Elevador"</li>
    <li>"Condominio"</li>
    <li>"Estacionamiento Visitas"</li>
    <li>"Bodega"</li>
    <li>"Estacionamiento cubierto"</li>
    <li>"ATM"</li>
    <li>"Colegio"</li>
    <li>"Farmacia"</li>
    <li>"Mall"</li>
    <li>"Parada Bus"</li>
    <li>"Parada de taxi"</li>
    <li>"Restaurante"</li>
    <li>"Supermercado"</li>
    <li>"Universidad"</li>
</ul>
```

See http://viper-7.com/hMxQLa (I pasted the required libraries - your code is at the end of the listing)